# how to disable tlp

Tags: tlp

I installed tlp <s>but I am wondering how would I disable tlp. I read the docs and it said to disable it you have to set TLP_ENABLE=0 but how would I do that.</s>

Is there a different way of disabling it from the terminal.

Comment: Do you wish to STOP it, or uninstall it? If you just wish to change that parameter, look in /etc/default for a file called, probably, tlp, and set it there. Or look for a similar file like tlp.conf in /etc.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your were on the right track. You actually have to change the config file as explained in the [documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/introduction.html#making-changes).

You must do this as root or with sudo:

```
sudo nano /etc/tlp.conf
```

If you have an older TLP version < 1.3 installed, it's a different file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/tlp
```

To determine your version, use the command

```
tlp-stat -s
```

and check the first line of the output for the version number.

Once in the editor change the line #26 from

```
#TLP_ENABLE=1
```

to

```
TLP_ENABLE=0
```

Remember to remove the leading *#*. Once finished leave nano saving the file with

```
Ctrl-X Y <Enter>
```

and reboot.